# MySQL PDO - does ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE return false on no changes?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm saving data from an API, and running a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The thing is that it saved without errors on the first go around, but on consecutive runs it returns false, with the following `errorInfo()`

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

I ran the SQL manually in phpMyAdmin, and it works (0 rows inserted), does this return false when no changes are made?

My apologies for horrible code here, the PDO instance is saved as `$this->db`
(I'm saving some JSON in this function, so the usual prepare escaping was erroring on the `:`, hence the "make-due" solution under)

```
public function update($table, $valuePairs)
{
    $columns = '';
    $values = '';
    $updates = '';
    foreach ($valuePairs as $column => $value)
    {
        if($value !== null and $value !== '') {
            $columns .= '`'.$column.'`, ';
            $values .= $this->db->quote($value).', ';
            $updates .= '`'.$column.'` = VALUES(`'.$column.'`), ';
        }
    }
    $columns = rtrim($columns, ', ');
    $values = rtrim($values, ', ');
    $updates = rtrim($updates, ', ');

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$columns.')
            VALUES ('.$values.')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.$updates;

    $result = $this->db->exec($sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
        print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
        echo '<br><br>';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look carefully at [`PDO::exec()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> PDO::exec() **returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted**
>   by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec()
>   returns 0.
>
> **Warning**
>
> This function **may return Boolean FALSE**, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

But your code does not make any distinction between zero and false:

```
if(!$result)
{
    print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

You probably want this:

```
if ($result===false)
{
    print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Getting zero rows updated when you run the statement twice is the expected behaviour because MySQL won't update a row if values do not change.

*I particularly prefer to forget about error handling and configure PDO to just throw exceptions.*

Comment: That is an amazing catch. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

[PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and [PDO::exec](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) return false only in case of failure.
Inserting no row and performing a successful update instead is not a failure.

An SQLstate of '00000' means no error.

Comment: That is weird, I get 00000 and false on these update runs.

Comment: Same for me. I do not get any errors - during an "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." it returns 'false', and the SQLState is '00000'. I'm trying to figure out what's going on, since the query seems to be correct.